# null from Clipboard

Tags: android, clipboard

I need to get copied data from clipboard. I use this code:

```
val clipboardManager = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
val clipData: ClipData? = clipboardManager.primaryClip
clipData?.let { textView.text = clipData.getItemAt(0).text }
```

If I use this code inside `onCreate()` or `onResume()` callbacks, I always getting null from clipboard.

But if I call this code:

```
textView.post {
        val clipboardManager = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        val clipData: ClipData? = clipboardManager.primaryClip
        clipData?.let { textView.text = clipData.getItemAt(0).text }
}
```

I get copied string.

So, I make conclusion, that Clipboard waits until all views are rendered.

Why clipboard needs to wait for rendering all views? Or maybe clipboard is waiting for something else

Comment: Maybe [this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33161782/10854225) can help, at the moment I can not test it, but I hope that this can help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is happening because your app should be in focus when you try to get `primaryClip` from Clipboard.

All views have to be set up and tied to activity, that's why you have to add your function to UI queue with help of `view.post { }`

That change was added in API 29 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#clipboard-data

Comment: Thank you for this valuable context. I was trying to understand why I couldn't get the clipboard data on the onResume. The clipboard primaryClip is null always for some reason - but putting my logic inside a `post` worked. Great stuff!

Comment: Follow up on this, found a great explanation on where to best use the Clipboard code - inside `onWindowsFocusChanged` worked for me. More details [here](https://medium.com/@fergaral/working-with-clipboard-data-on-android-10-f641bc4b6a31). I was getting an error saying `ClipboardService` couldn't be called and using that callback on my `Activity` did the trick